# Provide certificate file into pod in k8s

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, kubernetes, certificate

We a pod which needs certificate file
We need to provide a path to a certificate file, (we have this certificate) how should we put this certificate file into k8s that the pod will have an access to it
e.g. that we were able to provide it like the following to the pod `"/path/to/certificate_authority.crt”`
Should we use secret/ configmap, if yes than how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a TLS secret then mount it to the desired folder.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: secret-tls
type: kubernetes.io/tls
data:
  # the data is abbreviated in this example
  tls.crt: |
        MIIC2DCCAcCgAwIBAgIBATANBgkqh ...
  tls.key: |
        MIIEpgIBAAKCAQEA7yn3bRHQ5FHMQ ...
```

[Documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#tls-secrets)

To mount the secret in a volume from your pod:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mypod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: mypod
    image: redis
    volumeMounts:
    - name: foo
      mountPath: "/path/to/"
      readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - name: foo
    secret:
      secretName: secret-tls
```

[Documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-files-from-a-pod)

Comment: Thanks, but how should I provide the path to it ? for example I need to provide path like following https://vector.dev/docs/reference/configuration/sources/splunk_hec/#tls.ca_file

Comment: thanks for the update, I understand the volume part, I just miss something, what does it means `mountPath: "/path/to/"` how I need to provide the path to the secret key `tls.crt:` ?

Comment: @Jenney The values in your secret at mounted as separate files, so you find them at:  /path/to/tls.crt and /path/to/tls.key

Answer (score 1):

Create a secret, then mount it in the desired folder.

Official docs here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-files-from-a-pod

Comment: Thanks, but how should I provide the path to it ? for example I need to provide path like following https://vector.dev/docs/reference/configuration/sources/splunk_hec/#tls.ca_file , not sure I got it...

Comment: Not sure i'm understanding your question, but I guess it depends on your application.
If the application by default expects the file in a specific path, mount the secret there.
If you can override the settings, mount the secret where you prefer, then set the application to read that path.